# Avoiding Step Into common functions in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

It drives me crazy every time I want to step into my function, Eclipse steps into all the internal functions called during parameter construction.

For example, simple method call like this:

```
filter( Arrays.copyOfRange( sorted_words, 0, count), "count=" +count+ " words");
```

Goes through Arrays.copyOfRange, then StringBuilder constructor, then few calls to methods in StringBuffer, and eventually to my function.

Is there a way how to step into the called function and step over parameter construction? Or at least avoid common internal functions? Is the step filter the only solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step filters are one way to avoid stepping into types or packages that you want to avoid.

You can also use 'Step into Selection' debugger action. Quoting from the [JDT Tips and Tricks](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html) document -
*"The Java debugger allows you to step into a single method within a series of chained or nested method calls. Simply select the method you wish to step into and select **Step into Selection** from the Java editor context menu."*

Comment: Interesting, that would work nicely for me. Is there a shortcut for that?